# Error on set method of extensionAttributes

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I realize this question is kind of vague, but I'm hoping that someone with more knowledge of Magento than me can give me an idea of where to look.

I'm trying to add an extension attribute called `exportedFlag` onto Magento's `Invoice` class.

I'm getting an error in the following function that `setExportedFlag()` doesn't exist.  **However** the line above it for `getExportedFlag` does work, so I'd like to know how Magento creates the `setExportedFlag` method on `$extensionAttributes`, and where I should be looking to find a misconfigured setup that is preventing that method from being generated.

```
private function addExportedFlagToInvoice(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceInterface $invoice)
{
    $extensionAttributes = $invoice->getExtensionAttributes();

    if (empty($extensionAttributes)) {
        $extensionAttributes = $this->invoiceExtensionFactory->create();
    }

    $exportedFlag = $this->exportedFlagProvider->getExportedFlag($invoice->getEntityId());

    // This is the line that errors
    $extensionAttributes->setExportedFlag($exportedFlag);

    $invoice->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

    return $this;
}
```

Here is my `extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagInterface">
        <attribute code="exported_flag" type="MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagInterface" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Here's my `ExportedFlagInterface.php`

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;

interface ExportedFlagInterface extends ExtensibleDataInterface
{
    const INVOICE_ID = "entity_id";

    /**
     * Gets the flag that indicates whether this invoice has been exported.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExportedFlag();

    /**
     * Sets the flag that indicates whether this invoice has been exported.
     * 
     * @param string $exportedFlag
     * @return self
     */
    public function setExportedFlag($exportedFlag);

    /**
     * Gets this invoice's ID.
     * 
     * @return int
     */
    public function getInvoiceId();

    /**
     * Sets this invoice's ID.
     * 
     * @param int invoiceId
     * @return self
     */
    public function setInvoiceId($invoiceId);

    /**
     * @return \MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagExtensionInterface|null
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes();

    /**
     * @param \MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
     * 
     * @return self
     */
    public function setExtensionAttributes(\MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes); 
}
```

**Edit:** Another thing I noticed is that `generated/code/Magento/Sales/Api/Data/InvoiceExtension.php` has no methods within the class.  If I look at `ProductExtension.php` in the `generated` folder, that class does have several methods within it.  What might cause `InvoiceExtension` to not have any methods?

Comment: Have you added the extension_attributes.xml ?

Comment: Yes.  I updated my question with it.

Comment: type="MyCompany\InvoiceExportedFlag\Api\Data\ExportedFlagInterface" Can you also add the interface and it's implementation. If you want to just add single value flag, I would suggest to use:  type="string"

Comment: Sure thing.  I updated my question.

Comment: Yes, I do just want to add a single string value.  I've been following Magento's example where they add some links to products (https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-external-links), which is why I set `type` equal to `ExportedFlagInterface`.  Can I just set the `type` in that XML file to `string`?

Comment: Yes. Just set type="string"

Comment: I realized I had the `for` element of my `extension_attributes.xml` set incorrectly.  I fixed that, and now I'm not getting that error anymore.  Thank you so much for your help.  It got me looking in the right place.